# how can i convert editext value in integer?

Tags: java, android

this code of alertbox with edittext in this m geting the value from the user...i want to convert that value in integer n use in my code..

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Enter Your Weight");
    alert.setMessage("");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
     Editable  value = input.getText();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Weight is..."+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      // Do something with value!
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();
```

Comment: You can use Integer.parseInt( input.getText().toString);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setInputType to Number and it should not accept any decimal or character so i used KeyListener.

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
input .setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```

For converting into int

```
Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: thanx its works...:) i have a one problem with google map m drawing a path on map the code works  with gps update the problem is at the start and end points its continously draw a marker i want its only placed on start point and draw a path..plz help me ...thanx in advance....

Comment: Always Welcome Maddy.. I am looking to your new issue.. I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `EditText` contains String value so use `Integer.parseInt()` method of Java to convert `String` into `Integer`.

```
int numericValue = Integer.parseInt(yourEditText.getText().toString().trim());
```

Don't forget to `trim()` the value as `EditText` might contain a space while converting it to numeric.

Comment: thanx its works...:) i have a one problem with google map m drawing a path on map the code works with gps update the problem is at the start and end points its continously draw a marker i want its only placed on start point and draw a path..plz help me ...thanx in advance...

Comment: sure would like to help you, why dont you ask it as new question, it help you better from getting answers from other users as well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

**`int value  = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString));`**

Answer (score 1):

U can use the Integer.parseInt() to convert string into Integer.

or u can directly input the integer using set input type for edittext